# Gremlin Vertex label vs property

Tags: graphql, gremlin

In Gremlin, a Vertex can have labels and properties. What is the semantic difference between the two? Also, is the difference only semantic or is there a performance difference between querying by label vs querying by a property?
How should I choose what should be a property vs what should be a label?

Answer (score 2):

Some things may depend on the actual database being used, for example some databases may index properties but not labels. Likewise, performance may depend on the database being used when accessing a node by label or vertex property.

That said, in general labels are used to give a node a class such as "Person" or "Business" and properties contain information specific to each vertex. However, Gremlin today does not provide a way to delete or change a vertex label. So if you are likely to need to change values over time properties are the way to go.

I would use the general guidance that labels define the class and are immutable, properties can be updated and deleted and qualify each vertex in some way.

Answer (score 0):

Let me say the above in Column-oriented terms. So in gremlin you can consider 'Vertex/ Vertices' as table name you could say and 'property/ properties' are like columns!

E.g. Let us consider a use case like Facebook where it stores user data such as name, age, hobbies etc. Now in gremlin terms you could create a schema where Vertex ( Table name ) could be named as 'User' and for storing fields such as name, age etc. you could save them as properties!

The query would be,

```
g.addV('User').property('name', 'Alex').property('age', 23).property('hobby', 'Cycling').next()
```

And why storing these fields in properties instead of label? because for external indexes ( solar/ elasticsearch ) they return results more quick when comparing it with indexing vertex label.

https://docs.janusgraph.org/schema/index-management/index-performance/

Hope this has helped you :)